# Why isnt my delete trigger didnt delete any rows?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here is my trigger code:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `smartclass_dbv2`$$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_attendance_on_holiday` 
AFTER INSERT ON `attendance_tbl` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
     DELETE FROM `attendance_tbl` 
     WHERE (date = announcement_tbl.announcement_date && announcement_tbl.announcement_description = 'holiday'); 
END$$
```

It has no error however it doesnt delete any rows, my code means that if it finds any date on the attendance table that is the same with the date in the announcement table and it's a holiday, it will delete the row in attendance table.

This is my attendance table:

http://prntscr.com/j22rme

[image]

This is my announcement_table:

http://prntscr.com/j22rph

[image]

Comment: I would expect to see some reference to OLD. columns in a delete query (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) and shouldn't the trigger be ON announcement table?

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot change a table while the INSERT trigger is firing. The
>   INSERT might do some locking which could result in a deadlock. Also,
>   DELETING or UPDATING the table from a trigger would then cause the
>   same trigger to fire again in an infinite recursive loop. Both of
>   these reasons are why MySQL prevents you from doing this. [**Documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions)

**But you can run this query separately.**

Your Delete query is not correct check the below one

```
DELETE T1
FROM `attendance_tbl` T1
LEFT JOIN announcement_tbl T2 ON T1.date= T2.announcement_date
WHERE announcement_tbl.announcement_description = 'holiday';
```

**[Syntax Delete Using Joins](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/)**

```
DELETE T1 
FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN
    T2 ON T1.key = T2.key 
WHERE
T2.key IS NULL;
```

Comment: hmm now it says: "Can't update table 'attendance_tbl' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger." whenever im inserting something

Comment: i am inserting data on the attendance_tbl, and it is saying that i have an error

Comment: this is the trigger: DELIMITER $$ USE `smartclass_dbv2`$$ CREATE TRIGGER `delete_attendance_on_holiday` AFTER INSERT ON `attendance_tbl` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE T1
FROM `attendance_tbl` T1
LEFT JOIN announcement_tbl T2 ON T1.date= T2.announcement_date
WHERE announcement_tbl.announcement_description = 'holiday'; END$$

Comment: You cannot change a table while the INSERT trigger is firing. The INSERT might do some locking which could result in a deadlock. Also, DELETING or UPDATING the table from a trigger would then cause the same trigger to fire again in an infinite recursive loop. Both of these reasons are why MySQL prevents you from doing this.